# Do anti-ship drones sometimes intercept enemy energy shot weapons?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Sometimes I swear, on all that is holy, I see my anti-ship drone shoot an enemy laser out of the air as it leaves its gun. This is similar to how a Defense Drone Mark 2 will shoot lasers out of the air same as missiles, except it happens on the ENEMY SHIP side of the screen rather than the FRIENDLY SHIP side. Has anyone else ever noticed this?

Comment: The other day, I fired a laser and shot down an enemy attack drone that happened to be floating in front of the barrel.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Weapon collisions exist in the FTL. They're very unlikely, but they can happen. The projectiles and even *drones* from opposing factions can annihilate each other, as can asteroids.

This is a contrast to Defense Drone, whose role is to shoot down Missiles, Boarding Drones, and Asteroids. It's a further contrast to the Defense Drone Mark II, that can shoot down *incoming lasers*.

Comment: Can you source the collision information? This is almost gauranteed what happens as it matches the description of how sometimes I see this happen and sometimes it doesnt, but sources, sources, sources!

Comment: Can't find it, unfortunately.

Comment: This matches my programmer's intuition of how the game behaviour appears to be coded.

Comment: @rsegal I'm gonna accept anyway, this rings true so hard I feel like I'm nit picking.

Comment: It's easy to miss but it clearly happens every now and again.